# Defining and calling functions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I'm trying to call a function defined in an *external* .js using jQuery, but nothing happens. Here is my html:

```
<head>
    <title>Página de pruebas jQuery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--<link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" /></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="E1.js" />
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        Pasa el ratón por aquí
    </div>

    <div id="mostrador" style="display: none;">
        Muy bien, has pasado el raton por encima!
    </div>
</body>
```

And my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contenedor").mouseenter(mostrarTexto(evento));

    $("#contenedor").mouseleave(ocultarTexto(evento));
});


    var mostrarTexto=function(evento){
        $("#mostrador").css("display","block");
    }

    var ocultarTexto=function(evento){
        $("#mostrador").css("display","none");
    }
```

I've tried a lot of things I've searched, but i can't get it to work

Comment: first check whether jquery is in correct path..try to put alert inside document.ready(function())

Comment: Make sure the script files(jQuery library and E1) are properly imported in your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the script files(jQuery library and E1) are properly imported in your page.

And Try this.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/h9Veg/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contenedor").mouseenter(function() { mostrarTexto(); });

    $("#contenedor").mouseleave(function() { ocultarTexto(); });
});


    var mostrarTexto=function(evento){
        $("#mostrador").css("display","block");
    }

    var ocultarTexto=function(evento){
        $("#mostrador").css("display","none");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but you close your `<script>` tag twice.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="E1.js" />
</script>
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="E1.js">
</script>
```

Comment: because I call 2 .js files

Comment: Either way, closing the `<script />` inside the tag won't work. Remove the `/`.

Comment: @Magnus better to suggest in a comment line,I think here Answer not required for closing script tag.

Comment: While I do agree that it would have been more suited as a comment, self-closing `<script>` tags is still likely to not work. More about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: You should try it in combination with @Vasu's answer, and remove the self-closing from both your `<script>` tags if you haven't already. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the possible solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contenedor").mouseenter(function(evento) {
        mostrarTexto(evento);
    });

    $("#contenedor").mouseleave(function(evento) {
        ocultarTexto(evento);
    });
});


var mostrarTexto=function(evento){
    $("#mostrador").css("display","block");
}

var ocultarTexto=function(evento){
    $("#mostrador").css("display","none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is kinda wierd.

Why do you use

```
var mostrarTexto=function(evento){
    $("#mostrador").css("display","block");
}
```

why not

```
function mostrarTexto(evento){
    $("#mostrador").css("display","block");
}
```

and if you want to be falsifiable use the assignment bound to document root, not best practice but it helps when code gets ugly

```
document.mostrarTexto=function(evento){
    $("#mostrador").css("display","block");
}
```

And BEFORE all.. check if your function exists, and the scope of it. Because scope is a tricky thing.